# How can I set Visual Studio to use K&R style bracketing?

Tags: c#, formatting

I really don't like this style of formatting:

```
Class AwesomeClass
{
    private static void AwesomeMethod()
    {

    }

}
```

Can I make it format my code like this?

```
Class AwesomeClass {

    private static void AwesomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

Comment: For the casual reader who doesn't know what "K&R style bracketing" is, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style

Comment: I'm a recent convert to this style due to many discussions with a friend/developer on my team at work.  Thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Formatting** > **New Lines**.

In recent version of Visual Studio (at least 2017):

**Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Code Style** > **Formatting** > **New Lines**

Then just uncheck every option you see there.

Comment: Here's a secret feature, don't tell anyone: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3048800/timeline

Comment: It's a shame there's not equivalent settings for C/C++.  This default one character per line of code style is driving me insane.

Comment: There are now equivalent settings for C/C++ in VS2013

Comment: For VS 2019 the path is: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines

Answer (score 26):

Tools > Options

Check "Show all settings"

Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines

Uncheck the settings for where you want no extra newline added. Personally I always uncheck all items in this category.

Answer (score 5):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->New Lines

change all values to

"Keep on the same line, but add a space before"

then select a block and reformat with Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F

[image]