# Handling the this Keyword and Opening Braces with ReSharper and StyleCop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

I hope that someone can help me here.  I have hunted on and off over the past few weeks.  It is a two part question of things that are annoying me!

I do not like the this keyword stuck in front of everything.  Before I installed Stylecop I recall that ReSharper offered to remove these as redundant.  With StyleCop this no longer happens.  Worse when I reformat or otherwise fiddle with the code the this keyword seems to appear automagically where I did not ask for it.  I have tried turning off StyleCop's inspection for this and turning on ReSharpers.  RS does not offer to remove it.  I have concluded that it must be something to do with code formatting but I cannot find anything.

A smaller annoyance is that I prefer my opening brace on the same line as the statement it refers to.  Again it keeps getting shunted down. I wonder if this is in the same area and I am just not seeing the wood for the trees.

Comment: The brace settings can be changed in Options. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3048808/817630) for specifics.

Comment: With regards to the braces, having them on a separate line (GNU style) is a pretty well entrenched .NET standard. Having them on same line (K&R style) is the standard in Java. If other people need to read your code in the future it's probably best to stick to the standard which most people are familiar with.

Comment: @MattDavey  Thanks - I am a sole developer so having others read my code is less of an issue.  However I do like to set thinks out to a reasonable standard

Comment: correction to my above comment: the .NET standard is BSD style, not GNU style. GNU style is weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get resharper to ignore the `this` keyword by changing Resharper->Options->Languages->C#->Formatting Style->Other->Force "this." qualifier for instance member to 'Do not use'. Installing Stylecop always resets this setting to 'Use always'.

[image]

With regard to the braces, you can change them under Resharper->Options->Languages->C#->Formatting Style->Braces Layout and use the 'At and of line (K&R style)'.

Comment: Thanks for that - saved my sanity!  I guess I will repeat the above each time I update StyleCop....