# Can I view code with K&R indents while continuing to commit with Allman indents?

Tags: visual-studio, indentation

My workplace uses Allman style for indents in Visual Studio while I strongly prefer to read & write using K&R style. While I can [switch Studio to use K&R style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048808), that would be disruptive to everyone else.

Is there any way for me to view and write code in K&R while committing in Allman?